# qt crypto QCA is not compiling

Tags: qt, cryptography

I have installed the following qca packages for qca under Ubuntu 15.04:

```
  qca2-utils       
  qca-qt5-2-utils
  libqca2                    
  libqca2-plugin-cyrus-sasl  
  libqca2-plugins            
  libqca-qt5-2-dev
  libqca2-dbg                
  libqca2-plugin-gnupg       
  libqca-qt5-2               
  libqca-qt5-2-plugins
  libqca2-dev                
  libqca2-plugin-ossl        
  libqca-qt5-2-dbg
```

When running the command `dpkg -L libqca2` I get the following:

```
 /.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libqca.so.2.1.0
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libqca2
/usr/share/doc/libqca2/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libqca2/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libqca.so.2
```

The `.pro` file contains the entry:

```
CONFIG += c++11 crypto
```

and in the main.cpp I have:

```
 #include <Qca-qt5/QtCrypto/QtCrypto>
 #include <QtCrypto/QtCrypto>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

         QCA::Initializer init;

         return 0;
  }
```

But I get the error

```
     /main.cpp:37: error: undefined reference to `QCA::Initializer::Initializer(QCA::MemoryMode, int)'
```

Is there anything else I need to install or add in the `.pro` file?

EDIT:
Ok the comilation error could be solved but now I get Segmentation fault when calling `QCA::Initializer init;`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a link error, i.e. the headers are found, your code compiles but than the linker cannot create the final binary from your .o files and the libqca2 library.

You need to tell the linker that it should look for libqca. This is typically done by adding to the .pro (untested):

```
LIBS += -lqca
```

I don't know what `CONFIG += crypto` does because I never came across other config values than the ones documented here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#config and all Qt modules (including automatic linking) goes via the QT variable, e.g. `QT += core gui widgets`.

---

**Ubuntu's libqca2 is Qt 4 only!**

Regarding your segmentation fault: I think the problem is that [libqca2 is made for Qt 4 and you are using Qt 5 (right?)](https://forum.qt.io/topic/29652/solved-using-qca-results-in-segmentation-fault/11).

You can confirm that libqca requires Qt 4 here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/libqca2

I don't know if QCA is still maintained. So you might need to use it with Qt 4 or look for an alternative.

You might be able to compile QCA for Qt 5 yourself, but this is going to require advanced build system knowledge: https://github.com/JPNaude/dev_notes/wiki/Using-the-Qt-Cryptographic-Architecture-with-Qt5

Comment: Ok now it compiles but I get the error `The program has unexpectedly finished.`  when calling `QCA::Initializer init;` do you probably know what that is about?

Answer (score -1):

```
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
LIBS += -lqca-qt5_LIBNAME
```